# JSON datetime tracking custom formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to format a sharepoint list with JSON so that the From/To column highlights the current phone number when todays date falls into the timespan given.

[image]

I have managed to have past on future dates highlighted with the template from microsoft but it doesn't work properly when trying to highlight todays phone number. I guess it has to do with the fact that time needs to be considered as well.

[image]

Very many thanks for any help!

Best regards,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time component is considered automatically.

If I understood correctly what you want it that is Today(date and time) falls between From and To date, you need to highlight phone number.

Idea is to check and compare today's date with From and To one by one.

Pseudo code

```
If today <= From 
  Do not format
Else
   if today<= To
      Format
   Else
      Do not format.
```

I used below JSON

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
      "color": "=if(@now <= [$From], '',if(@now <= [$To],'#ff0000',''))"
   }
}
```

Below is output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using the code in JSON sadly it doesn't work and nothing is highlighted regardless of the date...

Comment: did you changed fields names according to your list?

Comment: {
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
      "color": "=if(@now <= [$From], '',if(@now <= [$To],'#ff0000',''))"
   }
} is how I pasted it which corresponds to what I have in my list...

Comment: also where are you adding this formatting code ?

Comment: are you column name 'From' & 'To'?

Comment: how can i add a screenshot here? I added it under format column, JSON (on the right) and then hit preview...

Comment: yes (see above)

Comment: only 3rd row should be highlighted right ?

Comment: yes, the 3rd row should be highlighted as per my local time.

Comment: working for me..check updated screenshot...can you please tell me in which field setting you are adding formatting ?

Comment: that worked - for some reason it did not do anything when I was adding it on the "quick edit" i.e. on the right of the list. When I went into list settings and added it to the respective column there it did the trick. Perhaps something to keep in mind. Many thanks again!

Comment: interesting....I will check this out...glad to help...please upvote and mark as answer...